# Blasting - how to calculate the charge concentration Ib (kg/m)?

Tags: energy, mining-engineering

I posted this question in physics, but they advise me to post it here so here I am.

I was looking for the formula to calculate the burden in bench blasting and I found this [document](//www.oricaminingservices.com/uploads/Blastec/Background%20to%20surface%20part%20calculations.pdf). The problem is I have to calculate the concentration of the charge first with the unit kg/m. I know that some materials are given but I need the formula to calculate other materials in which I have their energetic values calories/g calories/cm<sup>3</sup> ..

Comment: This document might be interesting: [Explosive Engineer's Guide](https://www.dynonobel.com/apac/~/media/Files/Dyno/ResourceHub/Brochures/APAC/Explosives%20Engineers%20Guide.pdf).

Comment: My understanding is the charge concentration, I$_b$ is the mass of explosive divided by the length of hole that contains explosive.

Comment: This seems to be a units issue, not an engineering issue.

Comment: @SolarMike: For those who don't know anything about explosives engineering & blasting, it's not a units issue. If anything, it's more of a terminology issue. The units at the end of the text are not important to what is being asked.

Comment: @Fred sure it is terminology issue no doubte on that, so since it is mass per distance can it be the velocity or pressure?

Comment: @SolarMike as i mentioned i was advised to post my question here but i think depending on engineering domaines equations, formulas, units are teached to be applied in all of them I THINK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge concentration, in kilograms per meter of drill hole, serves two purposes. The first is being able to determine the amount of explosives needed to blast a given amount of rock. This is needed when ordering explosives from the supplier or when taking out enough explosives from the magazine.

$M_{Explosives} \ = \ I_b \cdot N \cdot (L_H \ - \ L_S)$

Where:

- $M_{Explosives}$ is the mass of explosives required [kg]
- $I_b$ is the charge concentration [kg/m]
- $L_H$ is the length of the drill holes [m]
- $L_S$ is the length of the stemming [m]
- $N$ is the number of drill holes

The other purpose of the charge length is, if one knows the energy equivalent of each type of explosive [J/kg], for its given density of explosive, it becomes possible to calculate the amount of energy expended in the blast by the explosives used.

Comment: first thank you for the time you have gived to answer my question i apreciate that, so lets say the material is TNT it has 1.65 g/cm3 and 4.184 MJ/kg can you please add that as an example in your answer thank you again.

Comment: When you say "The charge concentration, in kilograms per meter of drill hole" you mean X kilograms multipied by numbers of meters deep of the hole? For example if the charge concentration is0.3kg/m TNT and a drilled hole is 7 meters deep stemming excluded this gonna equal to 0.3×7 = ~ 2.1 kgs total per one hole.

Comment: @Tintin: Regarding your last question with a charge concentration of 0.3 kg/m & a 7 m long hole, yes the mass of explosive in the hole would be 2.1 kg.

Comment: @Tintin: TNT is not a good example of an explosive to consider. It's basically a military explosive & rarely used for civil or mining purposes. It is mixed with other explosives as a compound, but I'm unaware of it being available as sticks. For surface mining & quarries ANFO or emulsion explosives are more likely to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much Fred that was very informative.

Comment: Hi Fred in the document of your first cemment page 10 i founded an equation can you please give it a look please .

Comment: @Tintin: Are you asking about the one that appears as a footnote for the table: $kg/m \ = \ 3.1415g\cdot D^2\cdot P/4000$?

Comment: Yes diameter exponent 2!! I know that Pi×d= circumference, and Pi×r2= surface m2. And about the number 4000 is it a constant? Thank you.

Comment: Area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, but the eqn uses diameter & $r \ = \ D/2$, therefore area is $\pi D^2/4$.  The 1000 comes about when you need to convert between kg & grams & $cm^3$ to $m^3$. Thus $10^3/10^6 \ = \ 10^{-3}$; and 4 times 1000 is 4000.

Comment: So; Kg/m = π • r^2 • P / 1000